# How can I install ubuntu on my flash drive if it is my bootable device?

Tags: 16.04

When I use rufus and put ubuntu on my flash drive, upon booting up ubuntu and choosing to install on something else, I cannot see the flash drive partition, just my hard drive partitions, I even tried 2 flash drives in my computer, none are detected.

I want to install ubuntu on my flash drive.

I can't get Wubi to work with 64bit iso, so that's not an option.

Comment: The problem is I boot the abuntu installer on my laptop using the flash drive, but when I want to install on the flash drive I'm booting abuntu up with, my flash drive partition doesn't show up, I'll try using a Virtual machine like Bobser suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about it being the "if it is my bootable device" however, I have managed to do a complete install on a flash drive that was able to be bootable. I installed virtual box with the extra plugin, added my usb to the filter, and started up a machine with no virtual disk but had it point to the iso file that I wanted to install. When I got it booted up, I went through the other selection and changed the partitions and such and managed to install it without a hitch. Even had a ntfs partition at the start of the usb so I can still use it as regular storage compatible with windows and had the OS install after it.

Comment: This worked and did exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!

Comment: No problem, I was trying to do the same thing for the longest time and tried the dual usb thing too and it didn't work out the greatest. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

1. Using VirtualBox is one good solution, as described in the answer by @BobserLuck.
2. Another good solution is to boot the live session (from the USB flash drive) with the boot option **`toram`**, which means that what is normally read from the drive will be copied to RAM and read from there when needed by the operating system. This means that you can do what you want with the USB flash drive, for example you can install the system into it. I would recommend that you use a [USB 3 drive with fast flash memory and at least 16 GB](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick#Notes_about_speed).
3. It is also possible to create a combination, to create a persistent live drive with [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) and after that create partitions for the installed system and install from the persistent live system into those partitions.

   The following steps should make the installation easy,

   - disconnect the internal drive
   - clone from a [compressed] image of a persistent live system into a USB pendrive, which is big enough. For example, there are [images, which expand to Lubuntu using 8 GB](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent/lubuntu). So if you use a 32 GB flash drive there will be 24 GB available for the installed system.
   - After the installation you should copy the `grub.cfg` file of the persistent live system into the installed system's

     ```
     /etc/grub.d/40_custom
     ```

     and run

     ```
     sudo update-grub
     ```

     and you will be able to select both systems from the grub menu, the installed and the persistent live system.